# How to set an environment variable from Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I set a new environment variable from within a `Jenkinsfile` using declarative pipeline?

I know that I can read environment variables using `env` like this one for example `${env.JOB_NAME}`.

But how can I set a new environment variable which can be be used by my build script for example. I want to do something like below. Is this the correct way?

```
stage("build_my_code") {
    steps {
        sh 'MY_ENV_VAR="some_value"'
        sh './my_script.sh $MY_ENV_VAR'
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to set a new environment variable in `Jenkinsfile` and then use that variable in an other declarative pipeline script or use it in  same `Jenkinsfile`?
Have you looked at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables or https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment ?

Comment: In the same pipeline, not in other pipeline. My build script needs an environment variable to be set. All I want to do is to set the environment variable in the `Jenkinsfile` before running my script.

Comment: You want to set a Jenkins environment variable or bash environment variable? Can you provide the console ouput of your job?

Comment: I want to set a bash environment variable

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323490/passing-variable-to-bash-script-in-a-jenkins-pipeline-job and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407976/defining-a-variable-in-shell-script-portion-of-jenkins-pipeline

Answer (score 4):

You can use `script` step to run Groovy script in declarative pipeline,
Then in `script` step to set environment by `env.xxx=yyy`

```
stage("build_my_code") {
    steps {
        script {
           // the MY_ENV_VAR environment variable should not exist, 
           // not allow to overwrite value of an existing environment variable.
           env.MY_ENV_VAR="some_value"
        }
        sh './my_script.sh $MY_ENV_VAR'
    }
}
```